# Maximum size Exceeded exception while uploading mp4 file to web api in mvc

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-web-api, restsharp

I am trying to upload mp4 format file to web api from rest sharp.But every time it gives me Maximum file size exceeded exception.I Put

```
 <security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

this code in my web api application  web config  file but no result.
I am calling my web api from other application in that I use Nuget RestShap to call web api.Please help me.
Code to call web api.

```
var request = new RestRequest("Uploads", Method.POST);
        request.AddFile("filename", Server.MapPath("/Images/videoplayback.mp4"), "multipart/form-data"); 
        request.AddQueryParameter("participantsId", "2");
        request.AddQueryParameter("taskId", "77");
        request.AddQueryParameter("EnteredAnswerOptionId", "235");
        request.AddQueryParameter("lat", "12.15");
        request.AddQueryParameter("lon", "12.56");
        request.AlwaysMultipartFormData = true;
        IRestResponse response = createClient().Execute(request);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also add this entry or add the attributes if you already have this entry in your web.config. The executionTimeout is in seconds and the maxRequestLength is in KB. Example is 2 hours and 1GB

```
 <system.web>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="7200" maxRequestLength="1048576" />
</system.web>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have to refer these links,you may get required stuff here...

http://www.strathweb.com/2012/09/dealing-with-large-files-in-asp-net-web-api/

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b5dbab38-9741-45ca-a791-1847b2935bb0/azure-api-app-rest-web-api-upload-limit?forum=AzureAPIApps